# Activities sharing loaded images

Tags: android, caching, android-imageview

Within one activity, I have images loaded from remote URLs, and store them in the LRU cache. When I go to another activity, how can I reuse the image in the cache and avoid loading them again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of options for doing this. One of them (the best one in my opinion) would be to create an instance of [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class to maintain global application state. Put you LRU cache there, and once it's filled by one activity, it can be used by any other activity later.

Android creates an instance of `Application` class when your application starts and remains it until it is closed. There is only one instance of `Application` class. It's a singleton. Any activity can access this instance by calling [Activity.getApplication()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication%28%29) method any time.